# JS - stop objects chaining without error

Tags: javascript, oop

I've got array of objects like chessboard, each of them has `top`, `down`, `left`, `right` function that returns object neighbour.

```
data.field(3,3).left() //returns field(2,3);
```

I can chain it like

`data.field(3,3).left().left().top().right().down().getName();`

But there is no object with negative cords like

`data.field(-1,0)`

Its easy to detect when given cords are negative or bigger than objects array. You can return false or empty object - but when there is nothing returned and chaining is continued there is an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<error> has no method 'down'
```

Which is ofc thing, but how can I avoid this error, and stop the long chain when there is no object to return without getting error that stops js executing?

Lets say:

```
data.left().left()/*here there is nothing to return*/.right().right().getName(); //should return false
```

Comment: You want to the chain to just skip over invalid calls and continue chaining as if nothing happened?

Comment: So, what would you want the entire line to return in the end?  Could you maybe return a "fake" object that has the methods, but no data?

Comment: lets say I've got 100 items chain that returns false on 10'th step. I want all the chain to return false (and for performance reasons that would be nice to stop executing 90 elements after false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of returning null for an invalid location, return a custom "null object" that overrides the directional functions to just return a null object with a getName function that returns "invalid location" , or throws an exception when those functions are called.

```
nullObject = {

    this.left = function(){return this;}
    this.right =  function(){return this;}
    //etc
    this.getName = function(){"Invalid Location"}

}
```

The exception handling could look like this

```
try{
  piece.left().right().down().getName()
}
catch(exc){
  //handle exception
}
```

Incidentally, you're essentially creating a monad here.  If you have it stop the computation when it receives the null object, then thats an example of the [maybe monad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29#The_Maybe_monad).  Thats a few theoretical levels above the practical concern here though.

Comment: there is no way to check anything when called function does not exsist

Comment: oh sorry true.  so don't return null, return a special type of object that is an invalid object that you can check against.

Answer (score 0):

`try/catch` structure allows you to stop execution in case there is nothing returned. However, if you don't want to use `try/catch`, each method must be able to return an object which owns the same methods which return the object itself. In this case the chain will be entirely executed :

```
right: function () {
    var nextItem;
    // get next item to the right here
    return nextItem || {
        up: function () { return this; },
        right: function () { return this; },
        down: function () { return this; },
        left: function () { return this; }
    };
}
```